# Multiple version sets and multiple APIs under each of the version sets to Azure APIM using terraform, Currently I get an error mentioned in the body

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, apim

I have used depends_on version set in my API resource but still get the below error

> Error - Future#WaitForCompletion: the number of retries has been exceeded: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ValidationError" Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:" Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"Can't set VersionName when ApiVersionSetId is not set.","target":"ApiVersion

Comment: Please make sure you add the code you are using to the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create APIM using terraform and set the version to that apim.
Whenever you try to create multiple versions of APIM , azure  creates a version set for that  particular API.

- You need to refer that version set Id to the APIM .

see: [azurerm_api_management_api_version_set | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_version_set)

```
  resource "azurerm_api_management_api_version_set" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-apimapi"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  display_name        = "ExampleAPIVersionSet"
  versioning_scheme   = "Segment"
}


resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-apim"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "xxxx@gmail.com"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-api"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "My Example API"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  version             = "v1"
  version_set_id      = azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.example.id

  import {
    content_format = "<>"
    content_value  = "http://xxxxapi.azurewebsites.net/?format=json"
  }
}
```

[image]

In case the version set is not updated ,import it using  terraform import  for the api having multiple versions
***`azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.example /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/group1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/service1/apiVersionSets/set1`***

**Reference:**
[Tutorial - Publish versions of your API using Azure API Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started-publish-versions)